# How can I measure each tuple's end-to-end latency in storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm, latency

I'm currently measuring a new grouping method in storm, thus throughput and latency matters the most, however I met with some difficulty when measuring the end-to-end latency of each tuple.

I tried to timestamp inside the tuple and calculate the latency when I received it in the downstream of my topology, but there exists negative numbers in the results.

Because I'm running the topology in cluster mode, time cannot be precisely synced among the machines in the cluster(i tried `NTP` but it's not precise enough either), which may be the cause of the issue.

So does Storm itself provide some kind of method to measure the end-to-end latency for each tuple? Or any trick I can use to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution to this!

We implemented our own spout and implemented the IRichSpout interface, in our `nextTuple()` method we assigned an unique ID to the tuple and put the timestamp into a `ConcurrentHashMap`, then emit with the ID by doing like

`collector.emit(new Values(str), ID);`

making storm aware that the tuple is assigned with an ID, thus in our `ack(Object msgId)` method, we check the time in hashmap by giving the key `msgId`, compare it with the current time, we got the latency for this tuple!

As we set the spout parallelism to 1 we don't have to worry the time syncing problem anymore.